# Would someone like to create the security-theatre tag wiki please?

Tags: discussion, tags, wiki

This tag seems to be coming in for a bit of abuse recently, I've seen a couple of questions in the last couple of days that have nothing to do with security theatre are tagged with it.

I've got some idea of what the phrase means by reading Schneier, but perhaps there's someone out there with more experience (or who's better at writing) who could create the wiki. If you have a good definition but not the rep to edit the tag wiki, post an answer here so the mods can work your text into the wiki. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I took a whack at it, but I cheated by citing wikipedia.

Feel free to make it more betterer!

https://security.stackexchange.com/tags/security-theater/info

Comment: Well that's one way, I suppose...